# What's the use of Map<String, String> getParams() while making Post method of Volley library?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-volley

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
{  
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        params.put("name", "Alif");  
        params.put("domain", "http://itsalif.info");

        return params;  
}
```

Whats the purpose of this method Map getParams() i.e. this only used in POST method of the Volley library.Where does the return values goes! Does it have any similar properties when compared with any part of AsyncTask???

Comment: The Javadoc clearly states `Returns a Map of parameters to be used for a POST or PUT request` -> hence they are sent as HTTP-GET or POST parameters to the server.

Comment: During a **POST** request the `getParams()` method is used for posting your parameters to your endpoint. i.e, the returned values are posted to your backend